# In React Nativigation how to update the state goBack

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

The above question says it all. I am having a StackNavigation of HomeScreen . HomesScreen has a component **Location**, and a state **location** , where location is stored to **AsyncStorage**.

Using **goBack()** function , I want to navigate to HomeScreen(navigating part is done) and **update** the state location. I want to update the location state to render the location in HomeScreen.

***HomeScreen render:***

```
<View>
<Text style=>{(this.state.location) ? (this.state.location) : ('Select Current Location')}</Text>
</View>
```

**Location Component**

```
await AsyncStorage.getItem('location').then((location) => {
            this.setState({location: location, persistedLocation: location})
        });
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('region').then((region) => {
            this.setState({region: region, persistedRegion: region})
        });
```

**Flow:**

[image]

**What to update the state on "goBack()" to HomeScreen ?**

**Is there any way to do it in better way ?**

Comment: `this.setState({location: location, persistedLocation: location})` is a async ,this might be the reason you are not getting updated value in your homescreen

Comment: why ? Even I have checked without await and async also. can you you tell if I can add a callback after goBack() is executed from -the location setter screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last after a lots of searching I finally found it here : https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/288 .

**In HomeScreen :**

```
   this.props.navigate("Location", { onSelect: this.onSelect });

  onSelect = data => {
    this.setState(data);
  };
```

**In Location Screen:**

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.goBack();
    navigation.state.params.onSelect({ selected: true });
```

A proper solution to all , for changing state of previous screen, passing values on goBack().